# Remove button after select jquery confirm button

Tags: jquery, jquery-confirm

How to remove that particular row of 'Revoke' button after jquery 'Confirm' button is being selected ? The code below is not removing 'Revoke' button permanently.

```
<td>
    <div class="btn btn-primary revoke-btn">Revoke</div>
</td>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.revoke-btn').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.confirm({
            title:'Confirm?',
            content:'Confirm to revoke?',
            buttons:{
                confirm: {
                    text: 'Confirm',
                    btnClass: 'btn-danger',
                    action: function () {
                        $(this).remove();
                        var link = $(e.currentTarget).parent().attr('href');
                        window.location.href=link;
                    }
                },
                cancel: {
                    text: 'Cancel',
                    btnClass: 'btn-default'
                }
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

> In the $.confirm, you can not get clicked element, so you need to get
>   the element in the variable then you can use this variable into
>   $.confirm action function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var isBtn = localStorage.getItem("button");

    if(isBtn == "Removed")
    {
          $('.revoke-btn').remove()
    }

    $('.revoke-btn').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var elem = jQuery(this);
        $.confirm({
            title:'Confirm?',
            content:'Confirm to revoke?',
            buttons:{
                confirm: {
                    text: 'Confirm',
                    btnClass: 'btn-danger',
                    action: function () {
                        localStorage.setItem("button", "Removed");
                        elem.remove();
                        var link = $(e.currentTarget).parent().attr('href');
                        window.location.href=link;
                    }
                },
                cancel: {
                    text: 'Cancel',
                    btnClass: 'btn-default'
                }
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Some explanation would make this a useful answer for the OP.

Comment: but after refreshing the page, the button is still at there

Comment: so i think you need to use browser localstorage for this functionality..

Comment: is there any example on that ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.revoke-btn').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var btn = $(this);
            $.confirm({
                title: 'Confirm?',
                content: 'Confirm to revoke?',
                buttons: {
                    confirm: {
                        text: 'Confirm',
                        btnClass: 'btn-danger',
                        action: function () {
                            console.log(btn);
                            console.log(this);
                            btn.remove();
                            var link = $(e.currentTarget).parent().attr('href');
                            window.location.href = link;
                        }
                    },
                    cancel: {
                        text: 'Cancel',
                        btnClass: 'btn-default'
                    }
                }
            })
        });
```

in action function  $(this) will not work for button you clicked. just print above output on console you will get it

Comment: after refreshing the page, the button is still there

Comment: you have to use local storage but this will wok only in one pc or browser. if you open this link in another browser or pc then button wil again appear